Opener Page Footnote span over two columns in twocolumn document
I am trying to create a template based on a twocolumn article. In order to fix all the opener page footnotes so that they span over two columns. MWE is below.
Compiler: lualatex-dev.exe (2024)
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,pdfversion = 2.0}}
    \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    \title{Title of the article\footnote{Title Footnote content with two lines. The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book}}
    
    \author{Author Name}
    
    \maketitle
    
    The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar\footnote{Body matter First column Footnote content with two lines. The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book} from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.
    
    The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.
    
    The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.
    
    
    The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar from\footnote{Body matter Second column Footnote content with two lines. The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book} traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.
    
    The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar from traditional grammar and/or introductory courses in morphosyntax are used. Section 1.2 discusses the position taken by the author about some concepts generally considered basic for the analysis of clause structure and its semantic correlates, and the terms used to refer to them. Section 1.3 presents the framework within which transitivity, valency, Opener Page Footnote text and voice are discussed in the remainder of the book.
    
    \end{document}

